What is the problem with this hard drive? (drive errors)
I'm having trouble with a hard drive that is (supposed to be) a part of a RAID5.
Here's is the smart log:
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-107-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     HUH721212ALE601
Serial Number:    8DHHX2AH
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 253d55276
Firmware Version: LEGL0002
User Capacity:    12,000,138,625,024 bytes [12.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jun  2 09:58:42 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   132   132   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       96
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   253   253   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       78 (Average 35)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       92
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   140   140   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       15
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       13784
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
 22 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
 45 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1095233372415
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       277
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       277
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   162   162   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 15/57)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   177   177   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1249778606260
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1530512354490

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 35 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 35 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13784 hours (574 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 01 68 08 00 00 40 08      00:16:02.030  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 30 06 00 a0 08      00:16:02.028  READ LOG EXT
  2f 00 01 30 00 00 a0 08      00:16:02.027  READ LOG EXT
  2f 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08      00:16:02.027  READ LOG EXT
  2f 00 01 30 08 00 a0 08      00:16:02.026  READ LOG EXT

Error 34 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13784 hours (574 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 01 20 08 00 00 40 08      00:16:01.440  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:16:01.440  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  60 08 00 08 00 00 40 08      00:16:01.427  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 f8 10 00 00 40 08      00:16:01.427  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 b8 08 00 00 40 08      00:16:01.427  READ FPDMA QUEUED

[...]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13784         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13386         -
# 3  Vendor (0x70)       Completed without error       00%     13326         -
# 4  Vendor (0x71)       Completed without error       00%     13325         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

As you can see several smart tests run througgh fine. However when i try to re-add the drive to my array, the drive keeps changing to a different device letter.
From the dmesg output, it looks like there is a communication issue as it seems to dial down the interfact speed (dmesg output below).
Is this a cable issue, is the controller at fault, or is really the drive defective? I have four of the drives in place, and this is the only one to cause issues - but I don't have a spare SATA port to test the drive at another port.
The fill dmesg is available here

If a long selftest works, and if udma crc errors go up, try a different cable / port / controller.

A long self-text doesn't work because:
The self-test routine was interrupted by the host with a hard or soft reset.
Will try a different cable tomorrow, and see if I can "borrow" another SATA port from another device not belonging to the RAID5. The CRC error count reimains the same, though:
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count 0x000a 170 170 000 Old_age Always - 42

Replacing the SATA cable seems to have done the trick. Using a new cable, the errors have disappeared.
